# C++: Decode a HTTP response which is Base64 encoded and UTF-8 decoded

Tags: c++, boost

I have a C++ program which is receiving encoded binary data as a HTTP response. The response needs to be decoded and stored as a binary file. The HTTP server that is sending the binary data is written in Python and following is an example code that performs the encoding.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import base64

# content of the file is string "abc" for testing, the file could be an image file
with open('/tmp/abc', 'rb') as _doc:
  data = _doc.read() 
# Get Base-64 encoded bytes
data_bytes = base64.b64encode(data)
# Convert the bytes to a string
data_str = data_bytes.decode('utf-8')
print(data_str)
```

Now, I want to decode the received data_str using a C++ program. I could make the python equivalent as below to work properly.

```
_data = data_str.encode('utf-8')
bin_data = base64.b64decode(_data)
```

But, with C++, I tried to use the Boost library's from_utf8 method, but no avail. Could anyone please guide the best way of decoding and getting the binary data in C++ (preferably using boost, since it is portable)?

Comment: The whole premise seems just wrong, and the whole UTF-8 encoding doesn't make sense. Once you have base-64 encoded the binary data it's using only 7-bit ASCII characters, which can be transmitted as is. On the receiving side you do a base-64 decoding and you have your original binary data. Just skip the whole UTF-8 bit.

Comment: The HTTP server performs UTF8 decoding since, the data has to be a valid JSON. The HTTP response should be a valid JSON structure. If I do not perform UTF-8 decode, then, I get the below error on the server. `TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Such details are very important to be able to help you, and as such should be in the question body. Please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I've used Base64 encoding/decoding in C++ but it isn't a very good idea to encode binary data, you should always opt to use the correct transport mode. In any case here's a snippet which does this: https://github.com/rapp-project/rapp-api/blob/cpp/cpp/includes/misc/misc.hpp#L14 which I copied from online sources

Comment: @Ron The output of base64 will be identical after UTF-8 encoding, as Base64 only uses 64 ASCII characters, for which the UTF-8 encoded are identical to the  input. All that remains is to base64-decode the data, for which there are plenty of libraries.